# Unit testing a class that depends on an async function

Tags: swift, async-await, continuations, swift-concurrency

I have a view model with a state property enum that has 3 cases.

```
protocol ServiceType {
    func doSomething() async
}

@MainActor
final class ViewModel {

    enum State {
        case notLoaded
        case loading
        case loaded
    }

    private let service: ServiceType
    var state: State = .notLoaded

    init(service: ServiceType) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func load() async {
        state = .loading
        await service.doSomething()
        state = .loaded
    }
}
```

I want to write a unit test that asserts that after `load` is called but before the async function returns, state == .loading .

If I was using completion handlers, I could create a spy that implements ServiceType, captures that completion handler but doesn't call it. If I was using combine I could use a schedular to control execution.

Is there an equivalent solution when using Swift's new concurrency model?

Comment: I'd use 'actor' instead of 'class' since you have a mutable state, and make 'state' private set.

Comment: @cora - it’s already on main actor, so no need to change to an actor. But I agree re `private (set)`.

Comment: @cora thanks for the suggestions, this is simply a throw away example though to help illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you're injecting the depencency via a protocol, you're in a very good position for providing a Fake for that protocol, a fake which you have full control from the unit tests:

```swift
class ServiceFake: ServiceType {
    var doSomethingReply: (CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) -> Void = { _ in }

    func doSomething() async {
        // this creates a continuation, but does nothing with it
        // as it waits for the owners to instruct how to proceed
        await withCheckedContinuation { doSomethingReply($0) }
    }
}
```

With the above in place, your unit tests are in full control: they know when/if `doSomething` was called, and can instruct how the function should respond.

```swift
final class ViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    func test_viewModelIsLoadingWhileDoSomethingSuspends() {
        let serviceFake = ServiceFake()
        let viewModel = ViewModel(service: serviceFake)

        XCTAssertEquals(viewModel.state, .notLoaded)

        let expectation = XCTestExpectation(description: "doSomething() was called")
        // just fulfilling the expectation, because we ignore the continuation
        // the execution of `load()` will not pass the `doSomething()` call 
        serviceFake.doSomethingReply = { _ in
            expectation.fulfill()
        }
        Task {
            viewModel.load()
        }
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.state, .loading)
    }
}
```

The above test makes sure `doSomething()` is called, as you likely don't want to validate the view model state until you're sure the execution of `load()` reached the expected place - afterall, `load()` is called on a different thread, so we need an expectation to make sure the test properly waits until the thread execution reaches the expected point.

The above technique is very similar to a mock/stub, where the implementation is replaced with a unit-test provided one. You could even go further, and just have an async closure instead of a continuation-based one:

```swift
class ServiceFake: ServiceType {
    var doSomethingReply: () async -> Void = { }

    func doSomething() async {
        doSomethingReply()
    }
}
```

, and while this would give even greater control in the unit tests, it also pushes the burden of creating the continuations on those unit tests.

Comment: `  let viewModel = ViewModel(service: serviceFake)` does not compile with error message "Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context"

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this the similar way you were handling for completion handler, you have the choice  to either delay the completion of `doSomething` using [`Task.sleep(nanoseconds:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(nanoseconds:)) or you can use continuation to block the execution forever by not resuming it same as you are doing with completion handler.

So your mock `ServiceType` for the delay test scenario looks like:

```swift
struct HangingSevice: ServiceType {
    func doSomething() async {
        let seconds: UInt64 = 1 // Delay by seconds
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: seconds * 1_000_000_000)
    }
}
```

Or for the forever suspended scenario:

```swift
class HangingSevice: ServiceType {
    private var continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Never>?

    deinit {
        continuation?.resume()
    }

    func doSomething() async {
        let seconds: UInt64 = 1 // Delay by seconds
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            self.continuation?.resume()
            self.continuation = continuation
        }
    }
}
```